# recording from webcam using ffmpeg at high framerate

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I have a webcam (model Brio 4K stream edition from Logitech) that is able to record at resolution 1280x720 and 60 fps in guvcview on Ubuntu 16.04. I then use a video codec 'raw camera input'. This is working fine and as expected, and the result is well a 60 fps video at the desired resolution.

However, I need to record using command line and not GUI. The guvcview GUI crashes on my machine (segmentation fault, this has been reported by other users before), so I want to use ffmpeg instead.

Unfortunately, when I use the command (in terminal):

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 out.mkv
```

I only get around 30 fps out. This is of course not due to the camera by itself (it works at 60 fps in guvcview), but I cannot understand why I get 30 fps when I ask for 60 fps explicitely. It also looks in the output of ffmpeg as it records at 30 fps:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
```

Any suggestion how I can solve this and record at 60 fps using ffmpeg?

**Note**: I also tried something like this, with the same result (only 30 fps):

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 -framerate 60.0 -video_size 1280x720 out.mkv
```

**Edit 1** thank you for the help in comment: order of arguments matters. Now using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video1 out.mkv
```

I get still around 30 fps, and a new (probably more understandable) warning message:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1ddc4e0] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/60 to 1/30
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 256338.694616, bitrate: 442368 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 442368 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

I find several entries for this problem (`video4linux2` + `The driver changed the time per frame`), but no clear solution.

**Edit 2 + 3**:

```
v4l2-ctl -d 1 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x180
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 340x340
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 424x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 440x440
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 480x270
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x448
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 848x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 960x540
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1024x576
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1600x896
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.008s (120.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x180
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 424x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 480x270
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x448
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 848x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 960x540
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1024x576
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.011s (90.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1600x896
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2560x1440
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 3840x2160
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 4096x2160
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)

    Index       : 2
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'NV12'
    Name        : Y/CbCr 4:2:0
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

**Edit 4**:

It looks like there may still be a problem using:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 out.mkv
```

As the output of ffmpeg looks like:

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'out.mkv':
  Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj422p(pc), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
  Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  198 fps= 37 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1043kB time=00:00:05.38 bitrate=1587.4kbits/s
```

Is the fps indicated in the last line (37 instead of 60) reliable? It was working at 60 fps with guvcview, so I do not think the laptop write speeed or CPU is the problem.

**Edit 5**:

Thank you for the great help @LordNeckbeard , now it looks like everything works using your additional output argument command `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -preset faster -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mkv`:

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -preset faster -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mkv 
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x1d6f320] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 259410.922692, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, -10 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[swscaler @ 0x1d7e480] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=4 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=20 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  467 fps= 59 q=-1.0 Lsize=     914kB time=00:00:07.83 bitrate= 955.8kbits/s    
video:910kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.434447%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.96  size: 61186
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] frame P:118   Avg QP:26.01  size:  4695
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] frame B:347   Avg QP:27.54  size:   734
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] consecutive B-frames:  0.4%  1.3%  0.6% 97.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] mb I  I16..4: 14.7% 45.2% 40.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] mb P  I16..4:  1.4%  3.7%  0.0%  P16..4: 29.9%  4.1%  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:60.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.4%  0.0%  B16..8:  5.4%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 4.3%  skip:89.6%  L0:53.4% L1:42.7% BI: 3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] 8x8 transform intra:66.4% inter:71.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.1% 50.7% 12.7% inter: 2.8% 7.6% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 36% 16% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 32% 37%  2%  2%  2%  4%  1%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 46%  8%  2%  3%  3%  4%  3% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 26% 16%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] Weighted P-Frames: Y:9.3% UV:7.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] ref P L0: 58.6% 41.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] ref B L0: 56.9% 43.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] ref B L1: 85.5% 14.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1d72620] kb/s:946.85
```

Comment: Option placement matters. Move `-framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720` before the `-i` so it applies to the input and not the output.

Comment: Thank you! Now I still get only around 30 fps, but a new warning message:

```[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1ddc4e0] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/60 to 1/30
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 256338.694616, bitrate: 442368 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 442368 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Show output of `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`.

Comment: see main post (limit in number of characters).

Comment: Which OS? I've had a project where the client encountered this. They upgraded and it went away.

Comment: I mention it in the post, but it is a bit hidden in the first sentence: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ;) I keep it up to date every day.

Comment: The camera does not indicate 60 fps in the output you provided, although the product specs show it should. Did you show the complete output from the `v4l2-ctl` command? Is there more than one camera on this system (such as above monitor on laptop)?

Comment: Yes:

$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext | grep 60
  Size: Discrete 640x360
  Size: Discrete 960x540
  Size: Discrete 640x360
  Size: Discrete 960x540

Comment: Probably another camera and it's accessing `/dev/video0`. Try again with `v4l2-ctl -d 1 --list-formats-ext`

Comment: updated in main post. You are right ;)

Comment: so I guess it means the fps I can achieve depends on the format / encoding I use? This would make sense.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Must choose proper format

This camera offers up to 90 fps using its MJPEG encoder, but only up to 30 using raw video, so you have to tell it which format you want with the `-input_format` input option:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 90 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 out.mkv
```

## If your computer is too slow to encode at realtime

[Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it first then re-encode later at your leisure to your desired format:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 90 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -c copy mjpeg.mkv
```

Then something like:

```
ffmpeg -i mjpeg.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mkv
```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg v4l2 docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Webcam](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe still some kind of problem though:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj422p(pc), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
```

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1038 fps= 42 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4083kB time=00:00:23.05 bitrate=1451.2kbits/s
```

Comment: @Zorglub29 Add `-preset faster -pix_fmt yuv420p` output options. As for inline "code" formatting use single backticks instead of triple, and for formatting a block of text in Q or A highlight it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting tips and for your updated command, it works great, see update main post.

Comment: PS: FYI: now that I know thanks to you that the camera *should* support 90 fps at 1280x720, I get a bit greedy and would like to enjoy it at full :) . But I do not manage to get 90 fps in guvcview, and it looks like I get max around 65 fps in ffmpeg. I got a warning message ```past duration too large```. If I am right (it is well known by google), it means I am hitting a bottleneck of some sort on my laptop?

Comment: @Zorglub29 Try to stream copy it and then later re-encode to your desired output format at your leisure: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 90 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -c copy mjpeg.mkv` then something like `ffmpeg -i mjpeg.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mkv` Also, your ffmpeg is old and I recommend [downloading](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a recent version.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly useful and I would never have found all of this without your help. It works fine for recording at 90 fps using stream copy. Do you want to edit your answer to add this or I add it as an edit in the question? ;)